# `pip install bpy` Not Working (LookupError: unknown encoding: future_fstrings)

Tags: python, scripting

When I run `pip install bpy` I get this error:

```
Collecting bpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/40/f8166da0a9c7f33bd0a942e9b86e83bd9ab07d85aabff6ffb7e0b939c3cf/bpy-1.2.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 397, in find_cookie
        codec = lookup(encoding)
    LookupError: unknown encoding: future_fstrings

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 449, in open
        encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 436, in detect_encoding
        encoding = find_cookie(second)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 405, in find_cookie
        raise SyntaxError(msg)
    SyntaxError: unknown encoding for '/tmp/pip-install-g68ruj02/bpy/setup.py': future_fstrings

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-g68ruj02/bpy/
```

I am using Ubuntu by the way!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems as if you are not required to install `bpy`, because it is already part of Blender.

Comment: Yes, the bpy is a part of Blender. The standalone bpy package can be used for background rendering without having to install Blender. Please note that the package offered on through pip / pypi is an unofficial package created by Tyler Gubala. The instructions for building Blender as a Python module can be found in the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule). The general instructions for building Blender can be found [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender).

Comment: But this does not answer the question you've asked. And I have the same issue :) but don't want to install blender.

Answer (score 16):

You are missing the future-fstrings package. I'm not sure why it doesn't install automatically but a simple `pip install future-fstrings` should solve this.

Comment: Man, you are awesome!