# "Installing" bpy for Plugin Development in VSCode

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to develop some blender plugins in VSCode. I'm familiar with writing python in VSCode, and thought that I could install `bpy` like any other python module so I could have intellisense features (i.e, Jump to definition, autocomplete) for bpy like I would any other python module installed in my virtual environment.

But from [`pip install bpy` Not Working (LookupError: unknown encoding: future_fstrings)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169561/pip-install-bpy-not-working-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-future-fstrings) I gather that there is no "official" bpy module to install.

What options does this leave me if I would still like intellisense features for `bpy` while writing my plugin?

```py
import bpy #can't install bpy and get intellisense
import geomdl #can install other python modules and get intellisense

from bpy.types import Panel

class SF_PT_PANEL(Panel):
   #my plugin panel script...
```

Comment: must read if you're using vscode https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/using-microsoft-visual-studio-code-as-external-ide-for-writing-blender-scripts-add-ons/

Answer (score 1):

After trying to get [blenderpy](https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy) working, I kept running into install issues. Doesn't look like the project recieves much active support.

After more research I found [fake-bpy-module](https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module), which got intellisense working.

Answer (score 1):

Just to unpack @ANimator120's answer and the fake-bpy gitpage itself:

To get the [fake-bpy-module](https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module) working on VScode in Windows:

- Install the package: from VS code terminal: `py -m pip install fake-bpy-module-latest`
- go to file->preferences->settings
- search for autocomplete python
- open settings.json it aill add the extra paths section at the bottom.
- you need to add the path to the site packages of your python dir (not the bpy folder like they say in the instructions) `py -m site` will help you here.

```json
      "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\YourUserNameHere\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages",       
      ],
```

- Finally, I had to throw down a `# pylint: disable=fixme, import-error` before the `import bpy` to make the linter stop complaining that it still cant actually import this.
- You should now have autocomplete

[image]